# Is there a way to make the contact preview easier to read?

Tags: contacts

Here is what I am seeing with both Chrome and Firefox on CiviCRM 4.6.4 with Joomla 3.4.1. It's hard to read and a bit jumbled. Is this a bug or can it be adjusted somewhere?

[image: Contact Preview]

Comment: Are you using a standard theme, or something exotic?

Comment: I second JoAnne's thought, it looks like a styling issue.

Comment: I didn't change anything, just what came configured with the standard installation. I checked the CiviCRM demo site and it looks the same for Joomla but the Drupal version looks good. Must be something specific to Joomla screwing it up.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the issue https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17484. This may help you to resolve issue.